# Error when getting disabled Azure Kevy Vault secret

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to use AZ powershell script to copy key vault with its secrets.
So, i have a "sourceKVName" and "newKVName"

Power shell script is called from the Azure Devops pipeline, and that DevOps project is configured with full access to the secrets in the source key vault

The part of the script that copies the secrets is this:

```
$secretNames = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName).Name
$secretNames.foreach{
    Write-Host Processing Secret Name $_
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $newKvName -Name $_ -SecretValue (Get- 
    AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName -Name $_).SecretValue
}
```

The problem I am havig is such:
Some secrets in the source Key vault are disabled.
And hence, when the loop encounters a disabled secret, I get an error
[image]

And I have no control over which secret gets disabled and when.  I just have to copy those "as is".
I understand that the error from
"**(Get-
AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceKvName -Name $_)**".

I am able to get all secrets properly when running that same command in the portal when I am logged in by myself.  So, the problem is only when doing it from within the ADO pipeline ..

Please, help .. I don't see anything in the documentation that helps.  I assume I have to either pass some option to the command or go to access policy and change something, but I do not know what.  The ADO pipeline has all the permissions to secrets.  As well as I as a user.

Comment: I sounds like an authorization issue?! Does the service principal of your ADO pipeline have Get Secret permissions?!

Comment: Yes, it does.  It has all the Set, List, Get .. etc.. permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have one Azure Key Vault having both **disabled** and **enabled** secrets like below:

[image]

I granted **full permissions** to DevOps service principal for secrets like this:

[image]

I used below PowerShell script to fetch secret names with their values  and got **same error** for disabled secrets:

```
$VaultName = "srikeyvault12"
$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName 

foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
    Write-Host "Secret Name: $($secret.Name)"
    $value = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $secret.Name -AsPlainText
    Write-Host "Value: $($value)"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you can only get values of **enabled** secrets. `Get` operation for disabled secrets is not supported. You can fetch disabled secret names but not values.

When I ran `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName`, I got below **response**:

[image]

Alternatively, I created **new version** with same secret value inside disabled secret by enabling it like below:

[image]

When I ran the script again, I got the **secrets** successfully like below:

```
$VaultName = "srikeyvault12"
$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName 

foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
    Write-Host "Secret Name: $($secret.Name)"
    $value = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $secret.Name -AsPlainText
    Write-Host "Value: $($value)"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get-AzKeyVaultSecret: Operation get is not allowed on a disabled secret by **BethanyZhou**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15378#issuecomment-872663026)

Comment: Thank you.  I understand.  I can enable the secrets and it will work.
The idea, however, is that I do not control the key vault.  So, potentially there maybe secret stored which are disabled.  The pipeline should NOT fail just because someone created it that way.